# iPhone crash log - what is the reason?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash, crash-log

I don't have much information when did it happened, because it didn't happened on my watch.
Anyone understand what was the reason?

Crash Log:

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x80624913
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37c38fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x32bc8cec -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewAnimationEnded] + 128
2   UIKit                           0x0061d7ee -[UIScrollViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) _scrollViewAnimationEnded] + 358
3   CoreFoundation                  0x309f8224 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
4   UIKit                           0x32b84c2a -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 606
5   UIKit                           0x32b845d4 -[UIAnimator(Static) _advance:withTimestamp:] + 260
6   UIKit                           0x32b844c6 -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 46
7   QuartzCore                      0x3219a41c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 160
8   QuartzCore                      0x3219a372 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 54
9   IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3577ff8c IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 76
10  IOKit                           0x31d2d88a IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 182
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30a62f3c __CFMachPortPerform + 356
12  CoreFoundation                  0x30a6d54c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30a6d4ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
14  CoreFoundation                  0x30a6c33c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
15  CoreFoundation                  0x309ef4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
16  CoreFoundation                  0x309ef39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
17  GraphicsServices                0x3361dfe6 GSEventRunModal + 150
18  UIKit                           0x32a6173c UIApplicationMain + 1084
19  MyApp                       0x00002304 0x1000 + 4868
20  MyApp                       0x00002298 0x1000 + 4760
```

Comment: Im getting the same error, no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a segmentation fault.  It seems like (just by observing the trace) there's some memory issue going on when the UIScrollView finishes a scroll animation.  Have you tried enabling NSZombies or putting a breakpoint that catches any kind of exception? I know you said it didn't happen on your watch, but if you could get a brief description of where it happened, maybe you can attempt to replicate it while debugging it in Xcode.

Comment: Is the dispatch part there is something that I called?